# How can I add columns without having to type out all of the column names?

Tags: r, dataframe, addition

Let's say I have 10 columns, and I want to add an 11th column that sums columns 1-6 for each row. How can I do this? I saw this on another answer:

```
data$newCol <- sum(data[1:6])
```

But that resulted in a single number for all rows in newCol, which isn't what I'm trying to do. The only way I know how to do this is like this:

```
data$newCol <- data$colA + data$colB + data$colC
```

and so on, but this gets tedious when I'm working with more than just a few columns. Is there a shortcut, like using [1:6] somehow? I'm sure this is such a beginner question, I tried searching but didn't see an answer that made sense to me, sorry.

Thank you!

Comment: You need `rowSums(data[1:6], na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: @akrun this one also worked, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `apply` function

```
data$newCol <- apply(data[,1:6], 1, sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

This code probably helps if I got what you had in mind:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(new_col = sum(c_across(col1:col6), na.rm = TRUE))
```